# How to run multiple shell commands incluiding Node.js server? Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a script that sequentially executes 2 instructions as following:

```
node server.js
node tests.js
```

- Server.js initializes a local Node.js + Express server
- Tests.js executes some unit tests on that server

The problem is that the first instruction keeps listening for requests, so the second is never executed.

Is it possible to solve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use the npm package `start-server-and-test` to be sure that your api server is ready to be tested

```
start-server-and-test 'node server.js' http://localhost:{API_PORT}/ 'node tests.js'
```